# Percentage value with GNU Diff

Tags: linux, unix, diff

What is a good method for using diff to show a percentage difference between two files?

Such as if a file has 100 lines and a copy has 15 lines that have been changed the diff-percent would be 15%.

Comment: You could use sdiff and count the separators, then divide by the number of lines.

Comment: diff fileA fileB | wc -l
divided by wc -l fileA //seems to be an interesting manual way to do it.

Comment: But the problem would be that when there is a difference, you get 3 lines -- orig, new, and description.  So you would probably overestimate.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

Two files, A1 and A2.

`$ sdiff -B -b -s A1 A2 | wc` would give you how many lines differed.  wc gives total, just divide.

The -b and -B are to ignore blanks and blank lines, and -s says to suppress the common lines.

Comment: from man file of wc: newlines, words, and bytes.
you divide the first number in the output by the number of lines in the file are you comparing.  wc -l, gives you only number of lines and can be added to the command above. -- Response to AlligatorJack

Comment: @cdated : thanks for clarifying.  I did not see the question/response of course until you commented.

Answer (score 13):

https://superuser.com/questions/347560/is-there-a-tool-to-measure-file-difference-percentage has a neat solution for this,

```
wdiff -s file1.txt file2.txt
```

more options see [man wdiff](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/wdiff.1.html).

Comment: I guess this only works for text as opposed to media like videos which I keep getting near-duplicates of (due to youtube-dl changing).

Answer (score 5):

Here's a script that will compare all .txt files and display the ones that have more than 15% duplication:

```
#!/bin/bash

# walk through all files in the current dir (and subdirs)
# and compare them with other files, showing percentage
# of duplication.

# which type files to compare?
# (wouldn't make sense to compare binary formats)
ext="txt"

# support filenames with spaces:
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

working_dir="$PWD"
working_dir_name=$(echo $working_dir | sed 's|.*/||')
all_files="$working_dir/../$working_dir_name-filelist.txt"
remaining_files="$working_dir/../$working_dir_name-remaining.txt"

# get information about files:
find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c "%s %n" | grep -v "/\." | \
     grep "\.$ext" | sort -nr > $all_files

cp $all_files $remaining_files

while read string; do
    fileA=$(echo $string | sed 's/.[^.]*\./\./')
    tail -n +2 "$remaining_files" > $remaining_files.temp
    mv $remaining_files.temp $remaining_files
    # remove empty lines since they produce false positives
    sed '/^$/d' $fileA > tempA

    echo Comparing $fileA with other files...

    while read string; do
        fileB=$(echo $string | sed 's/.[^.]*\./\./')
        sed '/^$/d' $fileB > tempB
        A_len=$(cat tempA | wc -l)
        B_len=$(cat tempB | wc -l)

        differences=$(sdiff -B -s tempA tempB | wc -l)
        common=$(expr $A_len - $differences)

        percentage=$(echo "100 * $common / $B_len" | bc)
        if [[ $percentage -gt 15 ]]; then
            echo "  $percentage% duplication in" \
                 "$(echo $fileB | sed 's|\./||')"
        fi
    done < "$remaining_files"
    echo " "
done < "$all_files"

rm tempA
rm tempB
rm $all_files
rm $remaining_files
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick-and-dirty `bash` solution using `comm`. Blank lines are ignored.

```
file_1="file_1.txt"
file_2="file_2.txt"
lines_1="$(grep -c '.' "$file_1")"
lines_2="$(grep -c '.' "$file_2")"
max_lines=$((lines_1 > lines_2 ? lines_1 : lines_2))
same_lines="$(comm -1 -2 <(grep '.' "$file_1" |sort) <(grep '.' "$file_2" |sort) |grep -c '.')"
diff_lines=$((max_lines-same_lines))
pct_change=0
[[ $max_lines -gt 0 ]] && pct_change=$((100*$diff_lines/$max_lines))
echo "Percent change = ${pct_change}% ($diff_lines of $max_lines lines are different.)"
```

Example result:

```
Percent change = 33% (4 of 12 lines are different.)
```

The `wdiff` and `sdiff` solutions are great, but those utilities are not usually installed in a default environment.