# How to generate hash from ~200k text/html that would match/compare to similar text?

Tags: mysql, performance, stored-procedures, mysql-5.5, function

I would like to make a sort of hash key out of a text (in my case html) that would match/compare to the hash of other similar text

ex of matching texts:

- "2012/10/01 This is my webpage #1"+ 100k_of_same_text + random_words_1 + ..
- "2012/10/02 This is my webpage #2"+ 100k_of_same_text + random_words_2 + ..
- ...
- "2012/10/02 This is my webpage #2"+ 100k_of_same_text + random_words_3 + ..

So far I've thought of removing numbers and tags but that wold still leave the random words.

Is there anything out there that dose this?

I have root access to the server so I can add any UDF that is necesare and if needed I can do the processing in c or other languages.

The ideal would be a function like `generateSimilarHash(text)` and an other function `compareSimilarHashes(hash1,hash2)` that would return the procent of matching text.

Any function like compare(text1,text2) would not work as in my case as I have many pages  to compare (~20 mil at the moment)

**Any advice is welcomed!**

#### UPDATE:

I'm refering to a`hash function` as it is described on wikipedia:

> A hash function is any algorithm or subroutine that maps large data
>   sets of variable length to smaller data sets of a fixed length.

the *fixed length* part is not necessary in my case.

Comment: A hash function behaves like a pseudo random value. If hash1 and hash2 do not match you know that text1 and text2 differs but I think it will not be possible to estimate the procent of matches from the hashes.

Comment: This is a highly interesting problem, but it's unlikely that you need a "hash" to do that. I think you need another data structure/concept, but I don't know the name of it.

Comment: I know, a hash probably is not the way most think of my solution, I mostly consider a hash, when used for large text, a way make text smaller. That's actualy what I'm trying to do so I cound make matches on it, but I want the oposite of the md5 hash, I want the colisions to be for similar text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that tag order in webpages can create a very distinctive pattern, that remains the same even if portions of *text* / *css* / *script* change. So I've made a string generated by the tag order (ex: `html head meta title body div table tr td span bold...` => "`hhmtbdttsb...`")  and then I just do exact matches between these strings. I can even apply the Levenshtein distance algorithm and get accurate results.

If I didn't have html, I would have used the punctuation/end-lines for splitting, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to utilize a  program like diff.

If you are just trying to compare text a hash is not the way to go because slight differences in input cause total and complete differnces in output. (Thus the reason why they are used to encode passwords, and secure text).  Character difference programs are pretty complicated, unless you really are interested in how they work and are trying to write your own I would just use a solution like the one that is shown here using sdiff to get a percentage.

[Percentage value with GNU Diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722947/percentage-value-with-gnu-diff)

Answer (score 0):

You could use some sort of Levenshtein distance algoritm. this works for small pieces of text, but I'm rather sure that something similar can be applied to large chunks of text.

Ref: http://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: Unfortunately this only solves a part of the problem, and I can't just compare 10mil rows with 10mil rows that's at least 90 Tera-comparisons. I need to summarize the text/html to some sort of hash and then do exact comparisons, or sub-part comparisons.